# Is there a way to display a UI Cell a single time and another UI Cell multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView which represent a questionnaire with Dynamic UI Cells. I've created 2 cells. 
The first UI Cell need to be all the time on the top (like a Title/Header) and the second UI Cell need to be Dynamic (this means that the second UI Cell can display 10 or 20 questions). Is there any way to do this ?

I've already created a UITableViewCell for both UI Cells and I linked all the components.
Now I don't know where to specify that Cell 0 to be returned 1 time and Cell 1 to be returned X times.
Also how I keep Cell 0 on the top all the time ?

Here is a printscreen which reflect my issue:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.row {

    // Static cell - Checks Left
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checksLeftCell", for: indexPath) as! ChecksLeftTableViewCell
        return cell

    // Dynamic cell - Questions
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.defectAndDamageCell, for: indexPath) as! DefectAndDamageCheckCell
        cell.configCell()
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: return 100
    case 1: return 400
    default:
        return 170
    }
}
```

I expect to have "frozen" cell on the top and the second one to be a dynamic cell.

Thanks if you read this and I hope that I explained well what is in my mind.

Comment: Why don't you add a UIView in top of your tableview and display the content of the first cell there?

Comment: You are right Omar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't sign of good thinking about design. It looks like you don't need `UITableView` at all. You can achieve better result using basic `UIView`s for each component such as *Title, question details, tags, etc.*

You can help yourself using `UIStackView`.

Comment: This seems to be the only option. I will remake the design. Thank you Robert.

Comment: @Flo acutally, it's not the only option. But for me this option looks like way to go. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a static cell you can use a Section Header with a custom View inside of it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: tabelView.frame.width, height: 40))
    nameLabel.text = //
    nameLabel.font = taskNameLabel.font.withSize(14)  
    //Or add whatever you need here     
    let sub = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabelView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    sub.backgroundColor = .white
    sub.addSubview(NameLabel)
    return sub
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.defectAndDamageCell, for: indexPath) as! DefectAndDamageCheckCell
    cell.configCell()
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using UICollectionView instead of the tableview. 
From UICollectionView, use the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate.

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView { #your code for header view }`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618037-collectionview

or

Create a section header in your TableView, and create a custom view in it.

So your TableView would have 1 section header and 1 row.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this.

If you want a static view that *sticks* to the top try this:
Subclass a `UIViewController` and add a container `UIView` at the top/leading/trailing. Embed your header labels and content in the content view. Next, add a `UITableView` and pin it to the leading/trailing/bottom of the superview. Make your view controller the data source and delegate.

In this way, you will still have scrolling within the tableview and can reload the cells as needed while managing your static header content as IBOutlets.

If you use the selected answer with stack views, you will have to implement a scrolling solution by embedding your stack view in a `UIScrollView` when your content is longer than the screen size. You should probably just stick to using a tableview because that behavior is inherited.